# Try to make a ComboBox that change the color of a circle can move

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcombobox, paintcomponent

Here's my code:

```
package driehoek;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Driehoek extends JFrame 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new Driehoek();
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        JPanel pnlTekenen = new GroeiendeCirkels();
        frame.setContentPane(pnlTekenen);
        frame.setTitle("Tekenen");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I don't know what i have to put below the ItemListener for the combobox and how do i change the names in de combobox
Code for `GroeiendeCirkels`:

```
 package driehoek;

 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

  class GroeiendeCirkels extends JPanel
  {
  private JButton knop1, knop2, knop3, knop4, knop5, knop6, knop7;
  private int diameter, breedte, hoogte;
  private JComboBox cmbSelect;
  private Color colors[] = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.PINK, Color.ORANGE};
    public GroeiendeCirkels()
    {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    diameter = 100;
    breedte = 150;
    hoogte = 150;

    cmbSelect = new JComboBox(colors);
    cmbSelect.setSelectedIndex(0);
    cmbSelect.addItemListener(new KnopHandler7());

    knop1 = new JButton ("Bigger");
    knop1.addActionListener(new KnopHandler1());

    knop2 = new JButton ("Smaller");
    knop2.addActionListener(new KnopHandler2());

    knop3 = new JButton ("MoveRight");
    knop3.addActionListener(new KnopHandler3());

    knop4 = new JButton ("MoveLeft");
    knop4.addActionListener(new KnopHandler4());

    knop5 = new JButton ("MoveDown");
    knop5.addActionListener(new KnopHandler5());

    knop6 = new JButton ("MoveUp");
    knop6.addActionListener(new KnopHandler6());

    add (knop1);
    add (knop2);
    add (knop3);
    add (knop4);
    add (knop5);
    add (knop6);
    add (cmbSelect);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(colors[0]);
    g.fillOval(breedte, hoogte, diameter, diameter);

    if (cmbSelect.getSelectedIndex()==0)
        {
            g.setColor(colors[0]);
        }
        else if (cmbSelect.getSelectedIndex()==1)
        {
            g.setColor(colors[1]);
        }
        else if (cmbSelect.getSelectedIndex()==2)
        {
            g.setColor(colors[2]);
        }
        else if (cmbSelect.getSelectedIndex()==3)
        {
            g.setColor(colors[3]);
        }
        else if (cmbSelect.getSelectedIndex()==4)
        {
            g.setColor(colors[4]);
        }
        else if (cmbSelect.getSelectedIndex()==5)
        {
            g.setColor(colors[5]);
        }

    }
    class KnopHandler1 implements ActionListener 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
    {
        diameter++;
        repaint();
    }
    }
    class KnopHandler2 implements ActionListener 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
    {
        diameter--;
        repaint();
    }
    }
    class KnopHandler3 implements ActionListener 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
    {
        breedte++;
        repaint();
    }
    }
    class KnopHandler4 implements ActionListener 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
    {
        breedte--;
        repaint();
    }
    }
    class KnopHandler5 implements ActionListener 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
    {
        hoogte++;
        repaint();
    }
    }
    class KnopHandler6 implements ActionListener 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
    {
        hoogte--;
        repaint();
    }
    }
   class KnopHandler7 implements ItemListener 
     {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent i)    
        {

            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

It won't work can somebody help me please?
It says that I have need a argument but given a Color. 
I know I did that but I don't see a other way.
I am a beginner in programmer so if you can explain it well I will learn something

Comment: Please clarify your question and post any error messages you are receiving.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor for your GroeiendeCirkels class is:

```
public GroeiendeCirkels()
```

So you don't need any parameters, but the code you use to create the class is:

```
red = new GroeiendeCirkels(Color.RED);
```

and you specify the Color parameter. So something is wrong. Either:

1. you need to add Color as a parameter for the constructor, or
2. you need to remove Color.RED when you create the class.

Also, I don't even understand why you are creating 6 different panels. The logic doesn't make sense to me. I would think you only need one panel and then the combo box contains the different colors of your circles.